# Why am I getting a "value must be known" error on tuple in a for-loop?

Tags: rust

```
struct Plugin;
struct Blueprint<'a>(&'a ());

struct Shell<'a> {
    plugins: Vec<(&'a Plugin, Vec<Blueprint<'a>>)>,
}

impl<'a> Shell<'a> {
    fn find_blueprint(&self, name: &str) -> Option<Blueprint> {
        for plugin_blueprints in self.plugins.as_ref() {
            for blueprint in plugin_blueprints.1 {
                if blueprint.name.to_string() == name {
                    return Some(blueprint);
                }
            }
        }
        None
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

Generates this error:

```
error: the type of this value must be known in this context
  --> src/main.rs:11:30
   |
11 |             for blueprint in plugin_blueprints.1 {
   |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This confuses me because `plugin_blueprints` seems to be unambiguously of type `(&'a Plugin, Vec<Blueprint<'a>>)`. I'm not sure what syntax (if any) I would use to specify the type in a for-loop. Turbo-fish `::<` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Why the `self.plugins.as_ref()` ? You are generalizing taking the reference where generalizing adds ambiguity. Try `self.plugins.iter()`

Comment: @user2722968 i'm still new to rust, so i'm sure i picked up as_ref() somewhere off the internet as a bad habit ^-^'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are using `as_ref`, which is more generic than you want. The value of `T` cannot be inferred:

```
pub trait AsRef<T>
    where T: ?Sized
{
    fn as_ref(&self) -> &T;
}
```

The idiomatic way to iterate over this is

```
for plugin_blueprints in &self.plugins {}
```

---

The pretty nasty way of doing it is to use the turbofish on the trait, using the disambiguated function call syntax:

```
for plugin_blueprints in AsRef::<[(&'a Plugin, Vec<Blueprint<'a>>)]>::as_ref(&self.plugins) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function will actually return a `Option<&Blueprint>` because you start with `&self`. You should also use `self.plugins.iter()` and `plugin_blueprints.1.iter()` to stop the ambiguity introduced by `as_ref()` and fix your lifetimes.

See [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?code=struct%20Plugin%3B%0Astruct%20Blueprint%3C%27a%3E(%26%27a%20())%3B%0A%0Astruct%20Shell%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20plugins%3A%20Vec%3C(%26%27a%20Plugin%2C%20Vec%3CBlueprint%3C%27a%3E%3E)%3E%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aimpl%3C%27a%3E%20Shell%3C%27a%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20fn%20find_blueprint(%26self%2C%20name%3A%20%26str)%20-%3E%20Option%3C%26Blueprint%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20plugin_blueprints%20in%20self.plugins.iter()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20for%20blueprint%20in%20plugin_blueprints.1.iter()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%20blueprint.0%20%3D%3D%20%26()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20Some(blueprint)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20None%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%7D&version=stable&backtrace=0)